# find out if the write end of a pipe is closed

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure a way to know when the write end of a pipe gets closed. Is there a way to do that somehow ?

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen('ls -lh', stdout = PIPE, shell = True)

def read_output(out,queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline,b''):
        print('.')

t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout,q))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while True:
    #this only works if I put 
    #if line == '' : 
    #    out.close()
    #in the for loop of read_output, which I want to avoid.

    if p.stdout.closed :  #need to find something else than closed here...
        break
```

iow I'm trying to avoid to have to do out.close() in the io Thread.... I want to somehow read a property or a method of p.stdout to know if its write end has been closed.

This is really not about finding another way to read Popen's p.stdout gracefully, I have 2 others ways already. It's more about learning something I thought should be possible, but I havn't figured how to do...

Cheers !

Comment: Why do you want to avoid closing the pipe? That sounds like trying to avoid the proper cleanup to do.

Comment: If you call `.read(1)` on a blocking pipe and it raises an error or returns an empty string/bytes, the pipe is closed. I am pretty sure that the pipes from `subprocess` are blocking.

Comment: The `EOF` condition is signalized by `read()` returning zero bytes. I don't know of any other portable method that does not include the `read`.  If you don't want to call the `read`, because it is blocking, you could you do a `select` first to check if the corresponding descriptor is ready (for reading). A descriptor is ready even if it is going to return empty result, i.e. the `EOF`.

Comment: Your pipe is finished when `readline` returns `""` and `p.wait(1) is not None`.
It shouldn't be closed until you let go of it, because the OS knows you may still be reading it! You requested this feature when you said `stdout = PIPE`.

Comment: You have a `read_output` function and thread target of `enqueue_output`. Is that intended? If so, what does that function do?

Comment: The `for` loop terminates, not when the write end of the pipe is closed, but when the read end finally reads all of the data. I assume that is close enough. In the current code, the for loop ends, the thread terminates and all you need is `t.join()`, which is something you need to do anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A write to standard output will cause an `IOError` to be raised if the pipe is broken.
You can detect this by catching the `IOError` and checking its `errno` attribute:

```
import errno

while True:
    print "Hello"
except IOError as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EPIPE:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Error writing to closed pipe"
```

Alternately, you can install a signal handler for when `SIGPIPE` is received.

```
import signal
def sigpipe_handler(e):
    # Do whatever in response to a SIGPIPE signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGPIPE, sigpipe_handler)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I'm looking for. p is a subprocess spawning a shell. p.stdout is written by the shell process, and read by me. I can't nor want to impersonate the shell process and try to write to its stdout. I just want to know if the shell process has closed its end of the pipe. Which if I was doing read_raw on p.stdout instead of readline would raise an EOFError, but since readline catches that, I just get nothing. I still believe there is a way to see the handle for the write side of p.stdout is closed though.

Answer (score 1):

I'll toss this in because it seems like the most obvious thing to do. The `for` exits when the last data is read from the pipe. This exits the thread which is the thing you can use to tell what happened.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = subprocess.Popen('ls -lh', stdout = PIPE, shell = True)

def read_output(out,queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline,b''):
        print('.')

t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout,q))
t.daemon = True
t.start()
t.join()
```

If you want to poll so that you can do other work, then

```
while True:
    if not t.is_alive():
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. One note is that the `b''` in `iter()` should be replaced with a plain `''` (at least in my testing - I was iterating over `sys.stdin.readline` in the child process, which might behave differently than a standard subprocess pipe)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly does [@caliloo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4334778/caliloo) mean by

> write side of `p.stdout` is closed

This statement suggests that there is another file descriptor writing to `p.stdout` which is wrong. The bytes being written to the file descriptor `p.stdout` comes from the process itself (`p` which runs the `ls` command) and not from any file handle. So reframing the question results in the statement

> the process of `p.stdout` is closed

To figure out if the process has exited or not, check the return code of the process, if the process has not exited yet, the return code will be `None`.

```py
p.returncode == None
```

Comment: Exiting and closing stdout are not identical. A program can close its stdout before it exits; this is particularly likely to happen if there was a great deal of content written to disk during execution that needs to be flushed; one can close stdout to let later pipeline components know there's no more content coming, and only then make sure that buffered content going to a non-stdout destination is all written.

Comment: One could also have a case where the shell _starts a background process_ that keeps its stdout handle open even after the shell itself has exited; the Python process won't see the read end of the pipe as closed until after _all_ handles on the write side are closed.

Comment: My attempt here is to strictly answer the question of what is the `write end of p.stdout`

Comment: I agree with what you said here. The problem is the question confuses about where the bytes being written to stdout comes from.